# Solving for the coefficent of linear equations with one known coefficent

Tags: matlab

```
clc;
clear all;

syms y a2 a3

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% [ 0.5  0.25  0.125  ]    [ a2 ]    [ y ]
% [  1     1     1    ]    [ a3 ]  = [ 3 ]
% [  2     4     8    ]    [  6 ]    [ 2 ]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

M = [0.5 0.25 0.125; 1 1 1; 2 4 8];
t = [a2 a3 6];
r = [y 3 2];

sol = M * t'

s1 = solve(sol(1), a2)   % solve for a2
s2 = solve(sol(2), a3)   % solve for a3
```

This is what I have so far. 
These are my output

```
sol =

 conj(a2)/2 + conj(a3)/4 + 3/4
       conj(a2) + conj(a3) + 6
  2*conj(a2) + 4*conj(a3) + 48


s1 =

- conj(a3)/2 - 3/2 - Im(a3)*i


s2 =

- conj(a2) - 6 - 2*Im(a2)*i
```

`sol` looks like what we would have if we put them back into equation form:

> 0.5 * a2 + 0.25 * a3 + 0.125 * a4
>
> a2 + a3 + a4 = 3
>
> 2*a2 + 4*a3 + 8*a4 = 2

where a4 is known == 6.

My problem is, I am stuck with how to use `solve` to actually solve these equations to get the values of `a2` and `a3`.

`s2` solve for a3 but it doesn't match what we have on paper (not quite). 
a2 + a3 + 6 = 3  should yield  a3 = -3 - a2.

because of the imaginary. Somehow I need to equate the vector solution `sol` to the values `[y 3 2]` for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide `solve` function with an equation. Just as simple as that:

```
 sol = solve(M * t' == r');
```

As a result you have

```
sol.a2 = 17
sol.a3 = -20
sol.y = 17/4
```

This works for MATLAB R2012b. In general this can be solved just in one line:

```
solve('a2 / 2 + a3 / 4 - y + 3 / 4 = 0', 'a2 + a3 + 3 = 0', '2 * a2 + 4 * a3 + 46 = 0')
```

P.S. I have checked, this works for MATLAB R2011b.

Comment: @Roemo Ah. Thanks. I try to do `sol(1) == some number`. But it didn't work out for me.

Comment: Quick question, @Roemo. I got `??? Error using ==> char
Conversion to char from logical is not possible.` I am using 2011b. Is there a problem?